# How can I add the Text Highlight Color control to a custom xml ribbon in PowerPoint?

Tags: powerpoint, office-addins, ribbonx, powerpoint-addins, powerpoint-2016

I'm building a custom ribbon in PowerPoint and would like to include the Text Highlight Color Picker control on it. I've found an idMso called TextHighlightColorPicker, but it's not recognised by PowerPoint so I just get an error when I open it.

```
<control idMso="TextHighlightColorPicker" size="large" label=" " />
```

I've tried various other idMso with the word 'highlight' in but to no avail. I imagine it's simply not available for custom ribbons, but I thought I check to see if anyone knows, because it's seems strange that most of the other buttons are available but not that one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that function is only available in subscription versions of PowerPoint 2016 for some reason: [Text Highlight Tool is not present in PowerPoint 2016](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/text-highlight-tool-is-not-present-in-powerpoint/897eaadb-01ce-456e-a894-faf915852142) - what version are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the idMso as per the instructions in Eugene Astafiev's answer, it turns out it is only avaiable in subscription versions. The id is "TextHighlightColorPickerLicense".

Comment: Marking your own posts as answers doesn't give any benefits to you.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such command available in PowerPoint 2016. You can find the list of commands available if you navigate to the `Customize Ribbon` on PowerPoint settings dialog:

[image: customize ribbon]

Here you can find the list of all available controls. And if you hover the mouse over any entry you may find the `idMso` value which can be used in the code for building a custom UI.

Comment: Ah, thanks this is very useful to know and actually led to me finding the idMso (TextHighlightColorPickerLicense), presumably the 'license' meaning you need a pay version (I'm running 365). Which ties in with your comment about it only being available there. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Then it makes sense to mark the answer. Self-posting doesn't make any sense since it doesn't give you any benefits or points. But following that way you can say thank you others who helped.

Comment: While your answer was very useful to me, I'm not sure it is actually correct to say that it's not available in Powerpoint 2016, because it is available in Powerpoint 2016 if you have an Office 365 subrscription.